# Could not access collabnet subversion edge server from remote computer on LAN over WIFI?

Tags: apache, svn, lan, collabnet

I have installed 
CollabNet Subversion Edge 2.2.0 (for Windows 64 bit) on Computer A(192.168.1.aaa) on LAN.

and try to access on Computer B(192.168.1.bbb) on same LAN by the url : http://192.168.1.aaa/svn/ giving me the timed-out problem.

But on Computer A I can access the the urls : http://192.168.1.aaa/svn/  and localhost/svn correctly.

Could somebody please help in configuring the server settings for remote clients.?

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to checkout a working copy on Computer "A" using `http://192.168.1.aaa/svn`? If that's the case, you know that Subversion is up and running, and Apache is up and running.

This looks like a network issue. Try *pinging* Computer "A" from Computer "B":

```
C:> ping 192.168.1.aaa
PING 192.169.1.aaa (192.169.1.aaa): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.aaa: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=19.476 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.aaa: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=19.476 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.aaa: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=19.476 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.aaa: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=19.476 ms
```

This will let you know if your network is making Computer "A" visible from Computer "B". If you're getting this:

```
C:> ping 192.168.1.aaa
PING 192.169.1.aaa (192.169.1.aaa): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
```

You know that the network between Computer "A" and Computer "B" is being blocked.

If you can *ping* Computer "A" from Computer "B", see if you can connect from Computer "B" to Computer "B" on Port 80. This is the standard HTTP port. Some companies block it for a variety of reasons. You can try this command:

```
C:> $ telnet 192.168.1.aaa 80
Trying 192.168.1.aaa...
Connected to 192.168.1.aaa.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

If you don't get the *Connected to 192.168.1.aaa* response, you know that port 80 is being blocked. In this case, you'll need to talk to your IT department about reconfiguring your network in order not to block Port 80. on machine 192.168.1.aaa.